# How to create a script to check for appointment availability on a government website

Tags: scripting, browser-automation

I would like to automate the process of checking [a government website](http://www.haute-garonne.gouv.fr/booking/create/24451/0) for available appointments. This would consist of:

1. clicking a specific checkbox ("Veuillez cocher...")
2. clicking a specific button ("Effectuer une demande...")
3. evaluating whether specific text exists on the page after step 2 ("Il n'y a pas calendrier disponible...")
  - If YES, repeat
  - If NO, stop and alert me somehow

I confess, I'm a total noob. My only reasonable alternative to this is to dedicate my life to checking this website manually until I get an appt.

I'm hoping this can run in a way that doesn't monopolize my computer. I'd like to be able to keep working while it runs.

I'd be so grateful for any help anyone can provide. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can wirte a python script by using Selenium. It works with many different progamming languages as you can see [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/). Even with [Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/webdriver).

There are a lot of turorials online on [youtube](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python%20selenium&t=ffab&atb=v165-3__&iar=videos&iax=videos&ia=videos).

You can find an explination for the following example on this [page](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You try using Selenium with Python. A useful chrome extension would be [Selenium IDE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd?hl=en-GB)

try looking into web automation. You could use casperjs and pahantomjs if you dont want to use python.

[Record CasperJS tests using Resurrectio](https://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/record-casperjs-tests-using-resurrectio)

Comment: Web automation was a good keyword. Thanks.